# xposed_init ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I have successfully installed Xposed on my device and i'm trying to compile a module to test it's functionality.

I have followed along [this](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial) guide and i'm stuck. I have created the xposed_init file in the assets folder and added the reference to my class called Test. (Reference should be correct since i right clicked and selected "Copy reference")

When i run the module and reboot the device, if i go to the xposed logs the result is "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class..."

What could have ever gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever find what was the problem? I'm stuck with the same issue and have no idea what else to try. I found another module on GitHub which compiles and works fine, but I don't see any differences not in manifest nor in xposed_init nor in any other part of the project. I'm totally out of ideas but almost sure it is something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Your run-time classpath does not have the jar included. The jar you included into the Build Path from eclipse is not available at runtime, but only at build time.

Like the author says [here](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial) ,

> This extended startup process adds an additional jar to the classpath
>   and calls methods from there at certain places.

Comment: I cant' continue myself tho, how do i fix it? Thanks for help man.